# Tiangolo flask docker image configure not to use port 80

Tags: flask, docker-compose

Is there any other way to configure this docker image `tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask`? I tried this on my `docker-compose.yml`

`version: '3'
services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
      - "8080"`

and my `Dockerfile`

`...
ENV LISTEN_PORT 8080
EXPOSE 8080
...`

Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the available configurations for that Docker image here: https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker